# WCF on .NET 4.5: Is there a definitive way to set MaxClockSkew on WsHttpBinding?

Tags: wcf

I host a public service (so I can't control client PC clocks). I'm using

```
 <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
 </security>
```

The max time difference allowed (MaxClockSkew) is 5 minutes.

What is the definitive way to disable this functionality and / or make it really large like 2 days?

The only safe, simple way I can think of is to just use transport credentials under https and pass the username and password to every method call. Surely I don't have to resort to this?

I've looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx and I don't fully understand it - i.e. where to apply in my world. I just use add service reference and the default proxies at present. Can it be defaulted in the server so that adding/updating a client reference picks it up?

Comment: Question is do you need to level of security that is provided by this security mode? 

I have a public service that uses message level encryption and we run into this clock skew issue often with client machines. To combat it we just implemented a unsecured endpoint on the same server that checks for the difference between the client and the server and warns the client of the clock skew problem before initiating the connection using the secured connection.

We looked at adjusting the max time but the number of edits to the WCF security setup that needed to be made changed our focus.

Comment: Hi, No I'm saying its public but it needs to identify the user to give them information that is tailored for them. I just feel like I'm hacking it if I just do transport level security and pass the usernames and passwords around, but that might be the answer.